# Equivalent of CURSORS from FoxPro in SQL Server and Oracle

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, oracle, sql-server-2012

In earlier days, FoxPro had this thing called Cursors, where data frames were added to and later processed. But, I wonder what is the equivalent of those in SQL Server and Oracle?

My guess is that we can make only one output table in SQL Server and Oracle, but if there is something equivalent please mention it.

For Eg.

```
SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE FName= 'David' INTO CURSOR **First_Name**

SELECT FName, LName, Contact, Email ;
FROM First_Name;
INTO CURSOR **Details**
```

Here First_Name and Details are Cursors. In working of this above program, information is first added to First_Name and then to Details.

Comment: Please only ask one question per question, you want an answer for SQL Server and Oracle, so ask 2 separate questions as the answers are most likely different. Also why tag MySQL? Do you want an answer for that RDBMS as well?

Comment: And ideally explain what exact a FoxPro cursor does, else you are limited to people who already know that answering.

Comment: Finally, what has your research on cursors for those RDBMS shown you? It would probably answer your question, or at least mean you have a more specific question.

Comment: FYI "SQL Server" is the actual name of the product from MS, hence doesn't need to be prepended with MS.

Comment: Other DBMSs have cursors, but they are by and large very slow, and should be avoided in favour of all-at-once set-based code.

Comment: How are you consuming this data?  Do you actually need two resultsets, or are you only interested in the Details?  Given your example, I do not understand why you are not simply doing `SELECT FName, LName, Contact, Email FROM Customers WHERE FName= 'David';`

Comment: I think you can probably emulate this cursor stuff by copying to temporary tables. Nice feature though

Answer (score 1):

When your background has been one language or system in particular, you tend to look at other systems through the concept of these languages instead of using them as they are intended to be used.

The answer to your questions is: Forget about FoxPro cursors. The reasons for their existence apply to FoxPro and don't exist in neither SQL Server nor Oracle.

These systems have something that is called cursor, looks very similar, but is used (or mostly not used) for very different reasons than a FoxPro cursor.

FoxPro mixes SQL and procedural languages. It does not optimize queries the way that SQL server or Oracle optimize a query. So the task to break up complex queries fell in the responsibility of the developer who uses cursors to optimize these steps. VFP processes cursors like a table, other RDMS do not.

First, stop thinking about the steps that you think you need to have accomplished and start thinking about what the result looks like. Then use the vastly superior SQL language to create a query that accomplishes this. In SQL you describe mostly what the result should look like and then let the RDMS figure out how. You don't have to specify every step. That is what the query optimizer is for.

A very common use of cursor in FoxPro are to create a intermediate result that is used several times in the following query. In both systems you would use a common table expression or a view to accomplish this.

The other common use is to post-process the cursor by updating individual columns before you use the cursor as a source for further processing. This is replaced with more complex queries (that can be broken up into views, common table functions or - if necessary - even functions) that produces the updated result in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

As of Oracle (as I don't know MS SQL Server), here are two examples which use explicitly declared cursor, cursor variable (to hold data cursor returns) and *relatively complex* way of handling the whole thing:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL>
SQL> declare
  2    cursor c_job is
  3      select distinct job from emp;
  4    c_row      c_job%rowtype;
  5    l_max_sal  emp.sal%type;
  6  begin
  7    open c_job;
  8    loop
  9       fetch c_job into c_row;
 10       exit when c_job%notfound;
 11
 12       select max(sal)
 13         into l_max_sal
 14         from emp
 15         where job = c_row.job;
 16
 17       dbms_output.put_line(c_row.job ||': '|| l_max_sal);
 18    end loop;
 19    close c_job;
 20  end;
 21  /
CLERK: 1300
SALESMAN: 1600
PRESIDENT: 5000
MANAGER: 2975
ANALYST: 3000

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

A simpler option is cursor `FOR` loop which is somewhat simpler as Oracle does most of the *dirty stuff* for you; as you can see, no more declaring cursor variable, opening the cursor, fetching from it, worrying about exiting the loop nor closing the cursor:

```
SQL>
SQL> declare
  2    l_max_sal   emp.sal%type;
  3  begin
  4    for c_job in (select distinct job from emp) loop
  5       select max(sal)
  6         into l_max_sal
  7         from emp
  8         where job = c_job.job;
  9
 10       dbms_output.put_line(c_job.job ||': '|| l_max_sal);
 11    end loop;
 12  end;
 13  /
CLERK: 1300
SALESMAN: 1600
PRESIDENT: 5000
MANAGER: 2975
ANALYST: 3000

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```